# Does OAuth uses ID Tokens for profile Information?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, openid-connect, websecurity

When we register to Spotify using Google or Facebook we'd using OAuth .  But OAuth is used for authorization . When used generates access tokens for specified API or resource . But when we use OAuth , it sends our profile pic and username too . Does it means it's using ID tokens (Open IDConnect ) as well for generating profile information .

And when logging in via Facebook , why do we require access tokens when we using them for authentication , instead we require ID tokens . Am I correct ??

Answer (score 1):

OpenId Connect is authentication and uses id token, and Id token basically says yes there is a user behind this machine who has logged in and granted access.

Oauth2 is just for authorization to authorize an application to access data on behalf of a user. an access token is granted to the application authorizing it to access the data on behalf of the user for a certain amount of time there is no grantee when using an access token that the user themselves is actually their accessing the data.